# Training set on R

Tags: r, set

I always wondered how the training set could be created through the use of square brackets. I am trying to run the ISLR book lab and I would be grateful if you would allow me to understand how this command works.

```
set.seed(1)
train=sample(c(TRUE ,FALSE), nrow(Hitters ),rep=TRUE)
test=(!train)
regfit.best=regsubsets (Salary∼.,data=Hitters[train ,],
nvmax=19)
```

How R can corresponds the observation in Hitters to the vector train?

Comment: Which part don't you understand? For example, do you understand the second line? the third? If the question is really only about how `Hitters[train ,]` works, that has an east answer: `train` is a logical vector with length `nrow(Hitters)`, which the `[` function accepts as a valid value for `i` (see `help('[')`). The logical vector's values match up 1-to-1 with the rows and the `TRUE` rows are kept.

Comment: I thank you so much. Now that I've read the help, it's much clearer to me. I wish you the best